# Local repository update

Tags: 16.04, apt, package-management, repository

I've got a local AMD64 xenial repository set up, starting at /media/charles/320GB/ubuntu.  AFAICT, it's an exact copy of the repository structure and files for 16.04, AMD64 architecture, for main, restricted, universe, and multiverse.

I have the following entry in my sources.list:

deb file:/media/charles/320GB/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse

When I try to run "sudo apt-get update", I get a lot of the following lines:

Get:4 file:/media/charles/320GB/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages [1,201 kB]

Ign:4 file:/media/charles/320GB/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

The only lines not like these are:

Err:7 file:/media/charles/320GB/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  File not found - /media/charles/320GB/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml (2: No such file or directory)

and

N: Can't drop privileges for downloading as file '/media/charles/320GB/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease' couldn't be accessed by user '_apt'. - pkgAcquire::Run (13: Permission denied)

What am I missing?